# make buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

In my HTML i have put a script and a div. Now i want to make 3 buttons next to each other in the `while` block in the middle of the page. I want to make the 3 buttons without changing the html and thus make it dynamic inside the javascript.

So far i have put a `var` in the javascript but i do not know what to do now..

I earlier made a html page with a button element inside it and then change all of it using the html but i cant figure out how to do this if there isn't a button element inside the html page.

**HTML:**

```
  <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="button.js"></script>
     </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html{
    background-color: grey;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsById("container");

button.onclick = onbuttonclicked;

function onbuttonclicked(){
    if (onbuttonclicked) {
        button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        button1.disabled=true;
    } else {
        button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        button1.disabled=false;
      }
    }
```

[image]

so like here each button has its own text and color

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to make the 3 buttons without changing the html so make it dynamic inside the javascript."? Also, `Elements` in `var buttons = document.getElementsById("container");` should not have an "s", as an ID can only be assigned to one element

Comment: i did add a small example image to it, like the background of the page is grey and there a little white block on the page, inside that white block i want to place 3 buttons

Comment: Yeah but I'm confused as to why you aren't putting 3 `button` elements in the HTML

Comment: The if statement in `onbuttonclicked` will always be true, as you're checking the value of the function, which is truthy. Instead you might want to evaluate the `disabled` property or the `backgroundColor` of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this you are trying to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript, take your `div#container` and you are trying to `append` three `button` elements. The process for doing this (or really any HTML Element with JS DOM manipulation is fairly similar, you create the element, add the attributes you want, and then "append" it to the main element where you want it inserted)
Check out my example below to add 3 buttons to your `<div id="container">`:

```
var container = document.querySelector("#container"); //or use document.getElementById("container"), makes no difference
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button"); //works with any HTML5 element
    button.setAttribute("attribute", "value"); //Use this to add attributes such as id, class, styles, or even event listeners like onclick
    button.innerHTML = "Button Text"; //Make sure to add button text if you don't want an empty button!!
   container.appendChild(button);
}
```

Since you said you want the buttons next to each other (I'm assuming this means side-by-side) then you can add a style to your CSS

```
button {
    display: inline;
}
```

but of course that would depend on your usage, meaning if you wanted all buttons to be `inline`. If you wanted just those three then you can use the `.setAttribute("class", "classname");` to add a class and then define that class to have the same style.

You can also make your container a CSS flexbox and have each of the buttons aligned horizontally

```
#container {
    display: flexbox;
    flex-direction: row; /*Use row for horizontal, column for vertical*/
}
```

and you wouldn't need to style your buttons. But the choice is yours.

Edit: to make 2 buttons, one green and one red,

```
//Make a green text button1
var button1 = document.createElement("button"); //works with any HTML5 element
button1.style.color = "green";
button1.innerHTML = "Button1 Text"; //Make sure to add button text if you don't want an empty button!!
container.appendChild(button1);
//Make a red text button2
var button2 = document.createElement("button"); //works with any HTML5 element
button2.style.color = "red";
button2.innerHTML = "Button2 Text"; //Make sure to add button text if you don't want an empty button!!
container.appendChild(button2);
```

If you wanted to change the background colors as well you could add `button.style.backgroundColor = "pink"` or whatever color you'd like

Check out: [JavaScript DOM Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp), this was a REAL help to me when I was learning what you're trying to do right now!

To give the buttons a function use the onclick value of the button, so in the above script we can add something like this:

```
button1.onclick = button1AfterClicked;
//Or
button1.setAttribute("onclick", "button1AfterClicked");
```

And since JavaScript is pretty lenient we can define our `button1AfterClicked()` anywhere

```
function button1AfterClicked() {
    button1.style.color = "some color";
    //And so forth...
}
```

For these kinds of questions I highly suggest looking up the answer on google because I know W3Schools does a splendid job on explaining the basics and more: [OnClick Event JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: Yes this is what i meant but now on all 3 buttons is the same text because of the innerhtml is there an other way to have different text on each button? like can i add a class or something on the buttons so i can change the text and the color of each button

Comment: Then instead of a `for` loop just write each one separately using different variable names like "button1", "button2" etc etc, and then call `container.appendChild(button1)` and `container.appendChild(button2)` the same, that way you can add different styles using `button1.styles.color = "red"` or something to that extent

Comment: This is what I have now but the color doesnt change and i dont get how to make them separately                                                                                                                                 var buttons = document.getElementById("container"); 
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button"); 
    button.setAttribute("button.styles.color", "green"); //Use this to add attributes such as id, class, styles, or even event listeners like onclick
    button.innerHTML = "Button 1"; 
    container.appendChild(button);
}

Comment: Yes, I now get how to make them separately, to change the size and stuff in the css i just need to add button1{ size: 40px;} for example or doesnt this work like that?

Comment: You have the right idea but the wrong CSS, your CSS selector would be the class or id that you add to the button since CSS can't access JavaScript variables, that's not how that works. And your style property would have to be valid as well like `width: 80px;` or `background-color: blue;`

Comment: so it isnt possible to change the width? and for example when you press button 1(red) the background goed red, when u press button 2(green) the background goes green and the same for the 3rd button

Comment: These are all separate questions, you'd have to use an onclick listener to change the background color of the button when it is clicked, or use a specific CSS selector. And yes you can change the width your CSS size thing just wasn't the correct way to do it. Ask another question if you need help with anything else

Comment: i just added an onclick event on the first button like this:

button1.onclick = onbutton1clicked;
function onbutton1clicked(){
    if (onbutton1clicked) {
       backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
       backgroundColor = "grey";
      }
    }

var button1 = document.createElement("button"); 
button1.style.color = "red";
button1.innerHTML = "Button 1"; 
container.appendChild(button1);

but how do i get it to work now?

Comment: Ask another question instead of making a really long comment chain, it'll also help other online users who need the same help

Comment: @desit900 it seems you already have an answer to that question in another one of your questions

Comment: i did add that to the code but then the buttons dissapear and doesnt work

Comment: Can you ask a new question on Stack Overflow with your code attached? I'd be more than happy to help you there

Comment: i have to wait 90 minutes until i can post another question

Comment: Ok I answered your question above, please checkmark the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Create the buttons and append them as children of your `buttons` container. Here I am creating one button. You can do the same for other buttons:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("container");
var button1 = document.createElement("button");
button1.onclick = onbuttonclicked;
buttons.appendChild(button1);

function onbuttonclicked() {
  if (onbuttonclicked) {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button1.disabled = true;
  } else {
    button1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    button1.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Note that `onbuttonclicked` will always evaluate to true because you are checking whether the function is defined or not. Also, if you want to change the background and disabled attribute of the **clicked** button, rather than **button1** explicitly, you should use `this` instead of `button1`.

Comment: oh okay so if you dont use an button element in the html you have to append in the js?

Comment: Yes, first create it then append it.

Comment: and if i want to change the size/color and stuff in the css do i just need to add: .button1{
    background-color: green;
} or something else because it is appended

Comment: Yes add the css style to the buttons

Comment: right now i did do what u said but now i dont see any buttons and the css isnt working either

Comment: @desit900 to use CSS you could either give each button an id or class to select them. Or use the container parent and the `:nth-of-child()` selector to style the buttons in order of appearance.

Comment: I will put the code you need in your project in 2mins

Comment: If you want to add inline style, use `btn.style.[property] = [property-value]`. For example, `btn.style.backgroundColor = "red"`.

Comment: when i add btn.style.backgroundColor = "red" all the buttons do dissapear

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or a stack snippet of what you are describing? It makes it much easier to help.

Comment: Hope that it will help you, The code provided is flexible for his use cases

Comment: @desit900 I just posted the code, hope it solved for you project

Answer (score 2):

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#container"); 
var arr = ['success','danger','warning'];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button"); 
    button.setAttribute("attribute", arr[i]); 
    button.innerHTML = arr[i]; 
    button.className += arr[i];
    container.appendChild(button);
    console.log(button)
}
```

```css
html{
    background-color: grey;
}

#container{
    top: 10px;
    padding: 82px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

btn {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.success {
    color: black;
    background:green;
}

.success:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

   
.warning {
    background: yellow;
    color:black;
}

.warning:hover {
    background: #ff9800;
    color: white;
}

.danger {
    background: red;
    color:black;
}

.danger:hover {
    background: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="button.js"></script>
</body>
```

I think like this?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it with jquery check is this right ?

```js
$("#container").html('<button class="green-button">Button1</button><button class="red-button">Button2</button><button class="yellow-button">Button3</button>');

$( ".red-button" ).click(function() {
 $(".red-button").css("background-color", "red");
});


$( ".green-button" ).click(function() {
 $(".green-button").css("background-color", "green");
});

$( ".yellow-button" ).click(function() {
 $(".yellow-button").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
 <div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is what might help you,you can set margin and padding to your needs:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
alert("did something");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is all you needed for your current project
You can add the style of the **button** in **CSS**

```
// container of buttons
const containerBtn = document.querySelector('.container');

let createBtns = (classParam, text) => {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add(classParam);
  btn.innerText = text;
  containerBtn.append(btn);
  return btn;
};

// 1. add the button **class**
// 2. add the button text

let btn1 = createBtns('btn-1', 'test');

// add event listener to btn1
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where three buttons are created and styled with CSS. They use the `nth-of-type()` and attribute selectors to style the buttons based on their position and disabled state.

Do note that when disabling the buttons they won't listen to the click event anymore.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = `Button ${i + 1}`;
  container.append(button);
}

container.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const { target } = event;

  if (!target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
    return;
  }

  if (!target.disabled) {
    target.disabled = true;
  } else {
    target.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container button {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#container button:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

#container button:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

#container button:last-of-type {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

#container button[disabled] {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```